# Good books on elasticity

Tags: resource-recommendations, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

Can someone suggest good books/textbooks/treatises/etc on elasticity?

Comment: Do you have a specific interest?  Phase transitions, studying elastic behavior, etc?

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with our not-so-old [book recommendation policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4698), here is a list of resources which were recommended without supporting details. If you write an answer that includes one of these, with appropriate detail, edit it out of this list.

- Landau, Lifschitz: Vol. 7
- Thorne and Blandford, online here: http://www.pmaweb.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2012/

Answer (score 0):

Two classical references are the following:

- Timoshenko, S.P, and Goodier, J.N. (1970). Theory of elasticity.
- Landau, L. D., & Lifshitz, E. M. (1959). Course of Theoretical Physics Vol 7: Theory and Elasticity. Pergamon press.

These two books present several solutions and physical insight. Nevertheless, they assume certain mathematical level from the reader. There are plenty of mentions of these in the literature, so it is good to know some of them.

If you are interested in a note detailed explanation of several topics in 2D and 3D and a variety of solutions, I would suggest:

- Barber, J. R. (2002). Elasticity. Dordrecht: Kluwer academic publishers.

Answer (score 0):

Landau, Lifschitz: Vol. 7

Atanackovic and Guran, Theory of elasticity for Scientists and Engineers

Comment: I thought that this is against the book recommendation policy