# Books/Chapters on Elasticity and Elastic Theories

Tags: resource-recommendations, harmonic-oscillator, spring, education, elasticity

I am a social scientist, and am working on a project that involves ideas from elastic physics, hooke's Law etc.
I was wondering if anyone had book/chapter recommendations  that summarize/introduce the ideas and theories of elastic physics!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9544/2451

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what depth you need, and what exactly you mean by elastic physics. If you want something introductory that just deals with Hooke's Law and Simple Harmonic Motion in general, I'd probably recommend any Physics I textbook. Things like "An Introduction to Mechanics" by David Kleppner and Robert Kolenkow, or "Berkeley's Physics Course Volume 1". There should be a chapter dealing with Simple Harmonic Motion in those books. Prerequisites for those would be mostly high school maths and some calculus (but not a lot).

If, however, you mean textbooks about Theory of Elasticity, dealing with deformation of solids and topics surrounding that, then the classic book is probably "Theory of Elasticity" by Landau and Lifshitz. Be warned that this one is exponentially more complex than the ones I recommended initially.