# Good references for Elastodynamics

Tags: resource-recommendations, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

I'm looking for a graduate-level reference about Elastodynamics.

If possible i would prefer it mainly rooted in vector notation better than Einstein notation (although i understand some proofs will be inevitabily carried out with this latter notation i guess).

Rigorous approach is best, with little intuitive notes is super.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9544/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general reference, I would suggest:

- **Graff, K. F. (2012). Wave motion in elastic solids. Courier Corporation.** This book it's a good starting point since it first presents the wave motion in simpler setups such as strings and rods and moves towards three-dimensional solids.
- **Achenbach, J. (1975). Wave propagation in elastic solids. Elsevier.** This book starts from the elasticity equations and moves from there. This is a "must-read" reference for some people.

On more advanced topics, I suggest:

- **Auld, B. A. (1973). Acoustic fields and waves in solids. Рипол Классик.** This is one of the best references that I have found when studying elastodynamics in anisotropic solids.
- **Carcione, J. M. (2007). Wave fields in real media: Wave propagation in anisotropic, anelastic, porous and electromagnetic media. Elsevier.** Besides anisotropic solids, this book considers anelastic media. Auld's book might be difficult to find, this is a good replacement.